# Torque/PBS can not find munge.socket.2

Tags: cluster-computing, virtual, fedora, pbs, torque

I am trying to create a virtual cluster for my MPI classes so i can work at home and not be at the university labs the whole day. I can not figure out for 2 days now how to fix this problem with munge.

The output of the problem i have is this

```
[root@localhost lumx]# qmgr -c "set server acl_hosts = mars"
munge_encode failed: Failed to access "/var/run/munge/munge.socket.2": No such file or directory (6)
Unable to communicate with localhost(127.0.0.1)
Communication failure.
qmgr: cannot connect to server  (errno=15009) munge executable not found, unable to authenticate
```

My hosts file looks like this

```
127.0.0.1    localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4 
::1         localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6
127.0.0.1 mpimaster localhost.localdomain localhost
```

I am tried to read as much as I could and I ended up with these guides,[Getting started with Open MPI on Fedora](https://dvbmonkey.wordpress.com/tag/torque/), [Installing Torque/PBS job scheduler on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS](https://jabriffa.wordpress.com/2015/02/11/installing-torquepbs-job-scheduler-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts/),[TORQUE Arch Linux](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/TORQUE), http://juanjose.garciaripoll.com/fedora-cluster/5-torque-pbs-queue

Answer (score 2):

I solved it. I just have to force it to start and use syslogs because there are some permission problems for now.

The command I use is

```
munged --force --syslog
```

Answer (score 0):

For Opensuse Leap 15.X, you need to start the munge service by

```
sudo service munge start

sudo service munge status
```

If the service is shown as active, you can verify it by now typing:

```
munge -n
```

That should return some results like below:

```
MUNGE:AwQFAAAHiPEv+E6Ezy2HVHUwo5PZ2fkbbr4yP7pZZA9Yo6BWQdAFGVRNkhNbRkvd9zNAvnpg0iQzkjg+WW6HdIix48nKrA0QnjispII4RoT1UqZLh7ybIl5/WIvd3ta85v1KV8A=:
```